# how to cancel a highlight in extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, highlight

How to cancel a highlight in extjs 4.1 ?

I call highlight() on a dom element in extjs 4.1. When highlight is running, I close (destroy) the panel, no error message, but dom operations after it throw some exception for example 'dom is undefine' and so on.

How to force cancel a highlight process before destroy ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
Ext.fx.Manager.stopAnimation(elId); // elId is the id of element which highlight
```

`Ext.fx.Manager` is private, but it seems work OK.

The animation engine seems not robust when the target element had been destroyed, and all effects after it won't had chance to run.

Or, has any method to auto remove all animations when a DOM element is destroyed ?